# Плавный Progress Bar

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Я использую счетчик от 5 до 0, с прогрессом в 1 секунду. Соответственно Progress Bar движется рывками по 1 секунде. Как реализовать горизонтальный Progress Bar с плавным ходом прогресса?

Answer (score 6):

увеличте кол-во делений с 5 до, например, 5000, и изменяйте прогресс, соответственно, раз в милисекунду.